# Can't open XAMPP & CodeIgniter Windows 10

Tags: php

In 2016/17 I had XAMPP working good but then I had one year rest and needed to reinstall Windows 10 and when I attempted to open the control panel it would not open.

I then decided to download the latest version of XAMPP and also CodeIgniter. I have transferred all of the files from the old version to the new version. I am able to open http://localhost/phpmyadmin and I have created a database with a table similar to that I had before. But if I enter http://localhost/intro I get the result of Object not found! - Error 404. I have checked routes.php and everything appears OK and I've also placed the Intro file (which is simple text without reference to the database) in the root folders of Controllers & Views, but get the same result. I have also checked config.php and changed $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/'; to $config['base_url'] = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/localhost/'; but again it made no difference. I also changed the port number in the Control Panel to 8080 but again made no difference.

I guess by being able to open http://localhost/phpmyadmin that indicates Apache is working OK.

Can somebody tell me where else I can check?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure xampp is running perfectly then add `.htaccess` file in the main directory of the intro, add the following code into it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

and try again. If you got any error let me help you.

Comment: Thank you. I looked in the old system and found a .htaccess file and there was not one in my new system. I copied & pasted that file and everything works good now.

My file contained a little more than yours as follows.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

Answer (score 0):

My old system had a .htaccess file and there was not one in my new system. I copied & pasted that file and everything works good now.

My file contained the following.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```